# Why doesn't vim print anything in console when running Python code?

Tags: python, vim

I am trying to write some python code using tornado. Here is my code.

```
import sys
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
import constants

class student():
    name = ""

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        loader = tornado.template.Loader(".")
        print "MainiiiHandler"
        self.write(loader.load("base.html").generate(pics=constants.pics))

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

So when i visit `127.0.0.1:8888`, it should print `MainiiiHandler` in terminal. When i run python code with 'python test.py', it turns out actually like this. But when i run with `:make` in vim, it won't print `MainiiiHandler`. Because i really like the make function in vim, so can you help me solve this problem.

Comment: Do you know exactly what command is executed by `:make`? I'd guess your script is not running at all.

Comment: `makeprg` is `python %`.

Comment: Weird. `:!python %` works but `:make %` doesn't.

Comment: I doubt vim does some output redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check how

> > makeprg is python %

is written.

```
:set makeprg="python %"
```

does NOT work for me (echoes an empty string)
while

```
:set makeprg=python\ %
```

actually DOES work.

(if it doesn't help) This is what :h make shows:

> The program given with the 'makeprg' option is started (default "make") with the optional [arguments] and the output is saved in the errorfile (for Unix it is also echoed on the screen).

If your system is not Unix, I suppose you have to supply the code that will print the contents of errorfile for you (don't know for sure as I tested it only under Linux).

Comment: Does it mean vim will display the 'stderr' strings. But when the output is in 'stdout' stream, then it won't display when compile in vim?

Comment: Yes, it does (I've tested both cases - when the program echos valid output or crashes with an error).
After I do ":set makeprg=python\ %" and ":make", vim shows the command it executes which is the following in my case:
":!python test.py  2>&1| tee /tmp/vivlQ2r/1"
(That means it takes both STDERR and STDOUT and sends it to tee program (through pipe) which saves its input to file AND prints to STDOUT)